# Javascript regex convert bracket [ ] notation to dot notation

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I am trying to convert some variables that are in the notation variableName[field1][field2] to the notation variableName.field1.field2

The reason I am doing this is because users can input variable names in the UI, and I don't want to straight up eval() them, so I run them through this function:

```
function getDescendantProp(obj, desc) {
   var arr = desc.split(".");

   while (arr.length) {
       obj = obj[arr.shift()];
   }
   return obj;
}
```

This lets it get the variable value without the need to evaluate code at runtime. Unfortunately that doesn't work if the variable is given in square bracket notation [ ]

Comment: Does the bracket notation contain quotes? Is it `[field1]` or `['field1']`? Or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic regular expression to convert it to dots

```js
var str = "variableName[field1][field2]"
console.log(str.replace(/\[([^\]]+)\]/g, '.$1'))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I couldn't find